# Using multiple transistor to increase current handling

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I need to make circuit that will convert 24v to 5v 4A. 
I have bought LM7805 mosfets and they are converting 0-40v to 5v 1.5A.
Problem is that I need minimal of 4A at the end so connecting 4 transistor in paralel should give me 6A on the output (6 * 1.5A)? I tried this and it does not work.

Comment: LM7805 is not a "transistor" -- it's a complete voltage regulator IC. Read its datasheet to find out how to increase current.

Comment: For that voltage drop and current, you should use a DC-DC converter (also called SMPS - Switch-Mode Power Supply)

Comment: Just because it's in a 3-pin package doesn't mean it's a MOSFET or even a transistor.  Look around for a buck converter module that can take 24V and deliver 5V at 4A.  Chances are high that it'll do just what you want, while consuming much less power while staying much cooler than a 24V to 5V linear regulator solution would have.

Comment: This will never work more than 10V input due to ignored thermal issues and wrong assumptions of IC. Buy a Buck regulator for 8 bucks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to make circuit that will convert 24 V to 5 V, 4 A.

OK, that will be 20 W out.

> I have bought LM7805 mosfets ...

The LM7805 is not a MOSFET, it's a complete voltage regulator.

> ... and they are converting 0-40v to 5v 1.5A.

If you were to draw 1.5 A while powering the regulator with 40 V you would have P<sub>IN</sub> = 40 × 1.5 = 60 W and P<sub>OUT</sub> = 5 × 1.5 = 7.5 W out. > 80% of your power would be wasted as heat until the device burnt out or shut down due to over-temperature.

> Problem is that I need minimal of 4A at the end so connecting 4 transistor in paralel should give me 6A on the output (6 * 1.5A)?

Maybe.

> I tried this and it does not work.

It is not clear what you mean be "does not work" and without a schematic I can't hazard a guess at what you have built.

A linear voltage regulator is a very poor choice for your application. You need a DC/DC power converter or a switching power supply which will efficiently step down the voltage. A good one should have an efficiency of around 90% and will avoid the horrendous heat problems your present approach would have.

Comment: Ok, I have found DC/DC converter, that will be enought for my project. I wasn't thinking about heat and efficiency so after rethinking all of that I am going with DC/DC converter. Thank you